# IoT usecase with Flink or Storm and Ignite

Tags: apache-storm, apache-flink, iot, ignite, complex-event-processing

I am weighing the pros and cons of design approaches for an IoT use case using Flink or Storm and Ignite. 
Consider I created a Rule Flow stating if any vehicle crossed the threshold speed limit set in the rule, then the flow should trigger an action to send SMS to drivers number. The flow I created is saving as a JSON in MongoDB. I have a list of 1000 OBD devices (which is continuously sending the data 3 times in a second) and associated drivers mobile numbers in another table in DB. In my design, I'm considering using an In memory DB too. Data collection is handling with Kafka.

What would be the fastest and most scalable implementation approach to update the flow with data (Unique ID of OBD device and Driver Mobile Number)? I have in DB and streaming data from each OBD device (current speed of the vehicle).

Comment: What is your criteria for "best?"

Comment: Performance(speed) and Scalability @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Ignite as a cache on top of the disk-based database, then you can have all updates to automatically propagate to both, in-memory cache and the database, using Ignite cache store with write-through and read-through features: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store